# ECRへのdocker pushでno basic auth credentialsというエラー

Tags: aws, docker

https://yomon.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/08/fargateselenium

上記のページの手順に従ってaws上でseleniumを動かそうとしましたが、docker pushのところでうまくいかず詰まりました。

```
docker push 123456789012.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/yomon8title
```

としたところ、

```
no basic auth credentials
```

というエラーが出てしまいました。
https://qiita.com/NaokiIshimura/items/1886dbd04631c3f7d0e1
などを見て、アカウントの権限、アクセスキーやシークレットアクセスキーも確認し、問題ありませんでしたが、依然として同じエラーがでます。
どのようにすればdocker pushができるか教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

公式ドキュメントに、 `no basic auth credentials` というエラーが表示される際のトラブルシューティングが記載されております。

[Amazon ECR 使用時の Docker コマンドのエラーのトラブルシューティング - Amazon ECR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/common-errors-docker.html#error-403)

こちらを参考に、

- 正しいリージョンに対して `docker login`を行ったか
- `docker login` の有効期限が切れていないか
- （追記）Docker for Windowsを利用している場合、 `aws ecr get-login` を行って生成されるコマンドから `https://` 部分を削除して実行

を確認してみてください。

また、念の為利用中のアカウントにECRへの書き込み権限があるかなども確認してみると良いかもしれません。

[Amazon ECR 管理ポリシー - Amazon ECR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html)

該当するリポジトリへの `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess` あるいは `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser` 権限を持っている必要があります。

なお、 `aws ecr describe-repositories` などのコマンドを実行することで、少なくとも読み込み権限が存在することを確認できます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
リージョンはap-northeast-1（東京）で統一し、docker loginをした直後にプッシュまでの操作を行い、かつアクセスキーを表示させたアカウントにAmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccessを付与しましたが、うまくいきませんでした。上記のコマンド"aws ecr describe-repositories"を実行した結果、以下のようなレポジトリが表示されました。
            "repositoryArn": "arn:aws:ecr:ap-northeast-1:281895324401:repository/yomon8title",
            "registryId": "281895324401",
            "repositoryName": "yomon8title",
            "repositoryUri": "281895324401.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/yomon8title",
            "createdAt": 1571797128.0,
            "imageTagMutability": "MUTABLE"

Comment: `docker login` は正常に実行できていますか（Login succeededという表示は出ますか）？また、Docker for Windowsを利用していますか？

Comment: $(aws ecr get-login --region ap-northeast-1 --no-include-email) を入力した後に表示されるコマンドをコピペし、login succeededという表示が出ていました。Windows powershellとDockerDesktop（Windows版）を使用しています。

Comment: もしかしたらDocker for Windowsのバグが原因かもしれません。回答本文を追記しましたので、参考に再度ログインから行ってみてください。

Comment: "https://"のみを削除してコピペ・実行し、ログインできましたが、それでもやはり no basic auth credentials エラーが出てしまいました…。何か私の方で見落としがあるのかもしれません…